# Admin script won't relaunch as admin on reboot

Tags: powershell, launch, administrator, reboot

I'm trying to run a script that will run another Powershell script upon reboot.  I'm using the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run key.

My problem is that the script launches upon reboot, but runs from a non-admin PS window.  This gives me "access denied".  I've disabled UAC on the system, but get the same error.
How can I get it to launch from Admin Powershell window when it reboots?

Currently have:

> REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v RunThis
>   /t REG_SZ /f /d "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell.exe
>   -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\script.ps1 -Verb Runas

Comment: Fixed sentence structure; tightened wording.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not get access denied when you run it manually, this should resolve the issue. Open the Powershell admin prompt. Key this in -

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Now add this to the Run key -

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file C:\script.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on a couple of factors: UAC settings; is the machine domain joined; etc...

This script will work in most scenarios. NOTE: The admin powershell host will close after the script completes execution.

```
$currentUserID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$currentUserPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($currentUserID)

$adminPrincipal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# If not already admin start a new process and pass the current session definition to the admin powershell instance.
if(-not ($currentUserPrincipal.IsInRole($adminPrincipal))) {
    $adminProc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "powershell"
    $adminProc.Arguments = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    $adminProc.Verb = "runas"

    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($adminProc)

    #If you don't need to keep the current session open uncomment this line.
    #exit
}

# Any code executed at this point will execute in an admin PS session.
ping google.com
```